# MySql select order by rand not working with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

Having table userid

```
Id
--
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

I would like choose rand id with comma separated, 
I have query as follows

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Id) FROM `userid` order by rand(Id);
```

But even used rand(Id) it displays result in ascending order as follows
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

expected result should be random & comma separated random order, How I can get? ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to put the `order by` in the `group_concat()` statement:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Id order by rand())
FROM `userid` ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'order by' is about all the results you get. And because you are getting only one result, you're randomising the order of that result.

What you could probably do is something like this, though it's hardly very efficient:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Id) FROM (SELECT Id FROM `userid` ORDER BY rand(Id)) a
```

This way you retrieve all Id's, randomise their order, and THEN group_concat them.

Side-note: if you are not doing anything more, you might just want to retrieve the id's and randomise them later? Otherwise you could take a look at this blog for better randomized retrieval: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Comment: it showing error "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: That's easy to solve, I'll edit, but keep in mind it was only a hint, you can probably take it from here with the manual? :D

Comment: (the 'a' I added is an alias for the table you get when doing the select)

Comment: yes, its working, actually I am trying to place alias after that error... Its amazing 'a'...

Comment: but always showing same result as 4,8,1,5,2,6,3,7, can you check this.. am i missing something?

Comment: this is an effect of using random without a seed I guess. There are a lot of sites and questions about how to use, but the real question is: do you need to do this query? why let the database randomise your results? good luck.

Comment: this is for quiz site, I have to select random question ids as comma separate, already I got solution from @@Gordon Linoff, Just like to know why same result in rand used query :) thanks

Comment: well, if speed is something you need, take a look at the link I posted. Instead of ordering by rand (expensive!) you can, if your id's are somewhat nicely distributed, find yourself a random number and then select it from an indexed id. much quicker!